# Best way to write loops with promises (ctx.sync) in JavaScript API for Office

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, ms-office, office-js

There are many threads that discuss about guaranteeing execution order of promises in loops. I would like to know what is the best practice in JavaScript API for Office Add-ins. Most of the time, the promise in question is `ctx.sync()`.

Here is a snippet to print the address of a list of Excel ranges one by one. The test shows that it respects well the order of Excel ranges. But the question is **whether and how to guarantee** the execution order?

```
function loadAll () {
   var ranges = ["A:A", "B:B", "C:C", "D:D", "E:E"];
   var sheet = "Sheet1";
   for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
       loadRange(ranges[i], sheet);        
   }
}

function loadRange (range, sheet) {
   Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
       var r = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheet).getRange(range);
       r.load('address');
       return ctx.sync().then(function() {
          console.log(r.address);
       });
   });
}
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: Why do you care about execution order? What does `Excel.run` return?

Comment: Excel.run() executes a batch script that performs actions on the Excel object model. The batch commands include definitions of local JavaScript proxy objects and sync() methods that synchronize the state between local and Excel objects and promise resolution. ([overview](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-javascript-programming-overview))

Comment: I do care about execution order... because I am going to some complex things inside rather than `loadRange` or `console.log(r.address)`, they are dependent to the order...

Comment: Then chain *those* things onto each other with `then`. I don't think you want to call `Excel.run` multiple times (or do you?)

Comment: I may have to call `Excel.run` multiple times... Moreover, it is a loop, how to chain them with `then` except for recursion?

Comment: In that case, if you need to call `Excel.run` multiple times, my question remains: What does the function return, a promise? If not, does it take a callback? If not, Is it even asynchronous?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a recursive approach here. That's how you write "loops" in asynchronous code.

Comment: `ctx.sync` returns a promise; `Excel.run` returns nothing I think. So are you saying that `Excel.run` might not be considered asynchronous from outside? So the order is always guaranteed for loops? (I don't believe so)

Comment: Yes, *if* `Excel.run` is synchronous from the outside (and that's a big "if"), then your code should just work.

Comment: From the docs you linked above: "*The run method takes in RequestContext and returns a promise (typically, just the result of ctx.sync())*". It's seems to be used only for garbage collection / resource allocation.

Comment: OK, then i think `Excel.run` is not considered synchronous from the outside. Because I just did a test: put a simple printing of a string after a function containing `Excel.run`, but i see the string is printed before what `Excel.run` prints...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `Excel.run` returns a Promise, you can chain it with a `.then` and guarantee order.  I.e.,

```
Excel.run(function(ctx) { ... return ctx.sync(); ... })
    .then(function() {
        return Excel.run(function(ctx) { ... return ctx.sync(); ... })
    })
    .then(function() {
        return Excel.run(function(ctx) { ... return ctx.sync(); ... })
    });
```

That being said... this would be pretty dang inefficient.  A much better approach would be to load all the objects you need in one batch, creating only one network roundtrip (especially important with Excel Online... but noticeable even on the Desktop):

```
function loadAll () {
    Excel.run(function(ctx) {
        var ranges = ["A:A", "B:B", "C:C", "D:D", "E:E"];
        var sheet = "Sheet1";

        var loadedRanges = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
            var r = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheet).getRange(ranges[i]);
            r.load('address');
            loadedRange.push(r);
        }

        return ctx.sync()
            .then(function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < loadedRanges.length; i++) {
                    console.log(loadedRanges[i].address);
                }
            });
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

If, as per comment, you do end up needing to do separate tasks that depend on each other and that each require a roundtrip, and hence do need to be sequenced via chaining `Excel.run`, I would recommend something as follows:

```
function loadAll () {
    var ranges = ["A:A", "B:B", "C:C", "D:D", "E:E"];
    var sheet = "Sheet1";

    // Create a starter promise object
    var promise = new OfficeExtension.Promise(function(resolve, reject) { resolve (null); });

    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
        // Create a closure over i, since it's used inside a function that won't be immediately executed.
        (function(i) {
            // Chain the promise by appending to it:
            promise = promise.then(function() {
                return loadRange(ranges[i], sheet);
            })
        })(i);       
    }
}

function loadRange (range, sheet) {
    return Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
        var r = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheet).getRange(range);
        r.load('address');
        return ctx.sync().then(function() {
            console.log(r.address);
        });
    });
}
```

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: Loading address is not a good example; actually, I am manipulating cell values and formulas step by step. I do need to chain `then` by a loop to realise serial asynchronous calls: the cell values and formulas in the current `then` depends on the manipulation in previous `then`; creating network roundtrip is expected. In this case, do you suggest recursion or `Array.prototype.reduce()` or something else?

Comment: Thank you for this nice structure, Michael... Additionally, I realise that if we add `return promise` in the end of `loadAll`, we could append `then` after `loadAll`, eg., `globalPromise.then(f1).then(f2).then(loadAll).then(f4)...`.

Comment: Great example, this exactly the starting point I was looking for and solved the issues I was having wrapping my head around using promises in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

The update of @Michael Zlatkovsky solves the problem of appending promises perfectly.
The complement added by @SoftTimur allows to wait for all promises to be done before doing a .then(), which is also very convenient !

My only remark about these posts would be if ANY promises throws an error, the other appended promises stop being treated.

In my case, the scenario is a little different. Just to clarify:

```
Excel.run(function(context){
    return runWorkbook(context, context.workbook)
        .then(function(){ var cool = "all promises worked !" }
        .catch(function(error)) { var bad = "do not want to be here :(" });
}

function runWorkbook(context, workbook){
    const sheets = workbook.worksheets;
    sheets.load("$none");
    return context.sync().then(function(){
        let promise = new window.OfficeExtension.Promise(function(resolve, reject) { resolve(null); });
        sheets.items.forEach(function(ws) {
            promise = promise.then(function() {
                return makeWorkOnWorksheet(ws)
                    .then(context.sync())
                    .catch(function(error)){
                        // DO NOTHING BUT CAN NOT THROW ERROR OTHERWISE IT BREAKS THE NEXT APPENDED PROMISES
                    });
        }
        return promise;
    }
}
```

This solution **works**.. (catch the error as in comment and doing nothing with it)

I don't like this solution but this is the only way I found to allow all appended promises to be done.

If somebody has a better idea, it's welcomed ;)

Cheers,

Comment: This type of code is called `pyramide of doom`. Use `async\await`.

Comment: Not true. If you can't use `async/await` your proposal doesn't work.
There is probably much better way to do it but related to the technical challenge I had to face to in my company, that was the only solution which worked.
And as an update, I would record errors from the last catch in a log file to allow programmers to face issues.

Also, I did that in my early beggining in JS/JS for Excel. My apologies if this code is not perfect/perfectly optimized.