# Excel Stops Responding When Applying Data From Add-In

Tags: office-js

I have an add-in using the OfficeJS API. I'm applying a 5x8784 chunk of data to a table with referencing formulas. I was having trouble with the speed / performance of the import, but was able to overcome most of the by turning calculations off prior to the import. My problem now is Excel stops responding about 1/4 of the time when I attempt to import data. There doesn't seem to be any particular pattern. Is there any way for me to detect what exactly is causing Excel to stop responding? Are there common mistakes I could be making in the add-in that would cause the data import to work most of the time but still crash Excel a handful of times?

Comment: Could you post your code?  Along with maybe some dummy look that creates data of the necessary size?

Comment: By the way, if I may recommend, it would be particularly helpful (both to us, and likely to you) if you can author the snippets in [Script Lab](https://medium.com/script-lab/you-can-write-javascript-in-excel-4ba588a948bd), and share them via that Script Lab functionality, so we can import them via literally 1 click.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. [Here is the shared Script Lab snippet](https://gist.github.com/enicoles/e6e786fea5613735583b5131940e8608). That snippet requires a table with a body range of 5x8784.

Comment: The shared snippet is a simplified of the overall application process, and probably doesn't give much context to the overall process. The typical process involves formulaically disabling referencing cells, applying data, then re-enabling the referencing cells. To verify that things happen in that order, I actually borrowed part of your approach [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900233/best-way-to-write-loops-with-promises-ctx-sync-in-javascript-api-for-office/37902306#37902306). Script Lab was giving me an error with the promises in that approach, so I didn't share.

Comment: If it's easier, I'd be happy to privately pass you our manifest file so you could directly pull in the add-in and see the entire process. The add-in accompanies a rather complex workbook that I could also privately pass you. At the end of the day we're trying to figure out if the non-responsive Excel is due to faults in the add-in, or the complexity of the workbook.  I'll add that I have your book and I appreciate the work you're doing with the Office.js. The book has helped to make sense of several topics for me.

Comment: Sure, having the manifest and real file would be great.  Feel free to email them to me at <first name> dot <last name> at <company I work for> dot com, and either myself or a colleague can investigate further.