# How to iteratively search with async in Excel

Tags: office-js

in my Excel Add-In I have stored an array of range addresses and I also know the currently selected cell. I'd need to iterate over all ranges defined by stored addresses and check if selected cell is in one of them (if there is an intersection). In the synchronous world it would be easy, but I'm not able to figure out how to do that in the asynchronous world of office.js.

I've found this post [Best way to write loops with promises (ctx.sync) in JavaScript API for Office](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900233/best-way-to-write-loops-with-promises-ctx-sync-in-javascript-api-for-office?rq=1), where Michal shows a nice pattern for chaining asynchronous calls, however, I have some questions.

Just to have the code here I'd copy paste it:

```
function loadAll () {
var ranges = ["A:A", "B:B", "C:C", "D:D", "E:E"];
var sheet = "Sheet1";

// Create a starter promise object
var promise = new OfficeExtension.Promise(function(resolve, reject) { resolve (null); });

for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    // Create a closure over i, since it's used inside a function that won't be immediately executed.
    (function(i) {
        // Chain the promise by appending to it:
        promise = promise.then(function() {
            return loadRange(ranges[i], sheet);
        })
    })(i);       
}}

function loadRange (range, sheet) {
return Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
    var r = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheet).getRange(range);
    r.load('address');
    return ctx.sync().then(function() {
        console.log(r.address);
    });
});
```

}

Questions:

1) Why there is a self-executing inner function in the for-i cycle?  Shouldn't be enough just:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    // Chain the promise by appending to it:
    promise = promise.then(function() {
        return loadRange(ranges[i], sheet);
    })
}}
```

2) I'd need to modify it to stop the chain if an intersection was found. How can I do that?

3) Would you recommend me some other approach how to iterate the excel objects (ranges, for instance) to search something (first empty cell in a column and so on)?

Thanks

Filip

Answer (score 0):

If you use TypeScript and the `async/await` syntax, the self-executing function and a bunch of the other weirdness goes away, and the code becomes much easier to reason over.  It will also make it trivial to exit for "for" loop.

I describe the use of TypeScript in great detail in my book, "[Building Office Add-ins using Office.js](https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins)" -- including why I think TypeScript is the best match for Office Add-ins, and how to set up for using TypeScript.  The entirety of the book samples, with the exception of an Appendix where I specifically show how to use plain ES5 JavaScript, are written in the TypeScript syntax.  There is also an overall primer on JavaScript and TypeScript:

[image: Chapter 4 Table of Contents]

For the question of how to better find an intersection:  If you prefer not to do address arithmetic (I wouldn't want to...), you can use the `range.getIntersection` method.  Or more precisely, if you're doing this for multiple ranges, the `range.getIntersectionOrNullObject` method, which is the non-throwing variety.  You can read more about the `OrNullObject` methods in the book as well:

[image: <code>OrNullObject</code> topics]

Hope this helps!

~ Michael