# How to highlight specific words in a selected range?

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

Basically I have to highlight the words that I am receiving in an array. On console I am receiving the following error after the first iteration:

Unhandled rejection PropertyNotLoaded: The property 'items' is not available. Before reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing object and call "context.sync()" on the associated request context.

Here's the code:

```
 var color = systemService.getColor(item.gradeText);
 var filteredWords = $(item.words).not($scope.stopList).get();

            Word.run(function (context) {
                var selectedRange = context.document.getSelection();
                context.load(selectedRange, "text");
                return context.sync().then(function () {
                    for (var i = 0; i < filteredWords.length; i++) {

                        var searchResults = null;

                        searchResults = selectedRange.search(filteredWords[i], { ignorePunct: true, matchCase: false, matchWholeWord: true });

                        context.load(searchResults, 'font');

                        context.sync().then(function () {
                            for (var i = 0; i < searchResults.items.length; i++) {
                                searchResults.items[i].font.color = color;
                                searchResults.items[i].font.bold = true;
                            }

                        });
                    }
                }).then(context.sync);

            })
               .catch(function (error) {
                   console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                   if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                       console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
                   }
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that adding the keyword `return` in front of the second `context.sync` fixes it.

Comment: It works but only for the first item of the array. I have 11 items in array but it only highlights the word in 0 index of array.

Comment: the return keyword ends the loop after applying styling to the first item. That is why I removed the return keyword.

Comment: Well, that's a different problem which you didn't mention in your question. You just asked for help with the error message.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your answer, I was able to get an idea about this functionality by this link:

[Best way to write loops with promises (ctx.sync) in JavaScript API for Office](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900233/best-way-to-write-loops-with-promises-ctx-sync-in-javascript-api-for-office)

Comment: I have to vote this down, even though the advice in the Stack answer that you link to is very good advice. But it doesn't answer the question that you asked, which was about the "Unhandled rejection PropertyNotLoaded: The property 'items' is not available" error.